# How to check if .Display email draft was sent or closed

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write some code in VBA to see if the draft window is closed, or if the email is sent. There are other things that will happen if the email is sent, and I don't want that code to continue if the draft is closed.

```
Sub SendEmail_Draft()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim row As Integer
For row = 2 To 1000
    If Cells(row, 13) = "Draft" Then
    
        Email = Cells(row, 4)
        Email_Subject = " "
        
        Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        EmailItem.To = Email
        EmailItem.CC = Emailcc
        EmailItem.Subject = Email_Subject
        EmailItem.HTMLBody = " " 

        EmailItem.Display
       'All the code below I only want to run if the email is sent,  otherwise I want the For loop to 
       'continue without completing the code below.

        Cells(row, 13).Value = "Completed"
        
        With Rows(row)
       '.Interior.Color = RGB(23, 213, 13)
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        
        End With
        
       Cells(row, 14).Value = Now
       Cells(row, 15).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
       Rows(row).Cut Destination:=Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       
    

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Create a new class `clsMail`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public rowNumber As Long
Public WithEvents mail As Outlook.MailItem

'this is triggered when/if the mail is send
Private Sub mail_Send(Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "sent a mail"
    FlagSent rowNumber  'call sub in regular module to flag row as "sent"
End Sub
```

For each mail you display, create a new instance of `clsMail` and assign the row number and mail object:

```vb
Dim pendingMails As Collection 'objects must remain in scope to fire events... 

Sub TestSendEvent()
    
    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Source As String
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem, objMail As clsMail

    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    EmailItem.To = "blahblah@blahblah.com"
    'EmailItem.CC = Emailcc
    EmailItem.Subject = "Test only"
    EmailItem.Body = "This is a test"
    
    Set objMail = New clsMail     'create a new object of class `clsMail`
    objMail.rowNumber = 15        'assign row number
    Set objMail.mail = EmailItem  'assign the mail item
    If pendingMails Is Nothing Then Set pendingMails = New Collection
    pendingMails.Add objMail      'add to "pending" collection
    
    EmailItem.Display
    
End Sub

'this receives a row number to be updated when a "send" event runs in
'  an instance of `clsMail`
Sub FlagSent(rowNumber As Long)
    MsgBox "updating row number " & rowNumber
    'code to update the sheet goes here
End Sub
```

There are some obvious limits to this approach, such as the mail only being sent after your workbook has been closed...